# Angular (click) on anchor tag is not working

Tags: angular

I am trying to use `(click)` but for some reason it's not working. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```html
<div *ngFor="let test of this.testingImages>
   <a (click)="test()">
      <img src="test.jpg">
   <a>
</div>
```

In the Component:

```js
test(): void
{
   console.log("clicked");
}
```

Comment: how do you know it's not working? Can you post what you are expecting to happen, and what is happening currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anchor tag is hijacking your events as should be expected. You can change it to a neutral element like a `div` or something or just put it right on your `img` instead;

```
<div (click)="test()">
   <img src="test.jpg">
<div>
```

OR even simpler;

```
<img src="test.jpg"
     (click)="test()">
```

OR a less preferred approach, negate it with;

```
<div [routerLink]="" (click)="test()">
   <img src="test.jpg">
<div>
```

Comment: I am noticing that only the content inside the *ngFor is not working using the (click)

Comment: @codingIT Sounds like you have something else in the way then amigo, move your click handler to the the div the ngFor is on (since that's the highest level of the repeating element) and should be good to go, beyond that would need to see a way to reproduce it since I can personally say I use the hell out of these techniques all the time. :D

Comment: There isa correct way to do it on an anchor tag, while the above works, it's not really what you should do.

Answer (score 4):

Use it like this

```
<a [routerLink]="" (click)="test()">...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way, add href without a value, this satisfies the DOM so it shows the right cursor.

```
<div *ngFor="let test of this.testingImages>
   <a href (click)="test()">
      <img src="test.jpg">
   <a>
</div>
```

In the Component, return false this prevents the anchor tag default functionality

```js
test(): boolean
{
   console.log("clicked");
   return false;
}
```

Comment: You [set void](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html) on a return so the bool may not be the best thing, but if you want it in a separate fn might just go with preventDefault / stopPropagation instead.